# Is this an adequate recipe for home made dog food?

Tags: dogs, health, diet

I feed my dog a home prepared meal made up of the following:

- 1 diced carrot
- 1 diced Broccoli head
- 1 large handful of Basmati rice
- 500 grams (1lb) of Heart Smart mince or 500 grams of organic chicken mince

This is all boiled in sufficient water until cooked and the water basically runs dry. I then freeze individual meals in sandwich bags to use as required. I have a small Maltese and he gets 1 sandwich bag (about 2 large table spoons) of this morning and night. Is this healthy and sufficient for him?

Comment: when I googled "Heart Smart mince" I came up with beef and pork - which meat are you feeding?

Answer (score 2):

FYI: our vet has been helping us with raw food for our dogs for years. We have several dogs in the family ranging from 15lb to 70lb. In general you have the right mixture, 1/3 veggie, 1/3 carbs, 1/3 proteins. I would double check the amount though. I would contact either known breeders or a Maltese rescue society, you will be amazed how much info they are willing to provide. Good luck!